# Ruby SketchUp ... add a measurment

Tags: ruby, sketchup

still learning about Ruby + Sketchup!

Today,I would like to add a measurement (good english word ?) as I can do manually with the 'cotation' (french version) tool when I click to point then drag the measure text.

Can't find that in the docs to do with Ruby and API ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the Sketchup::Entities::add_dimension_linear method.
http://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Entities.html#add_dimension_linear-instance_method

Assuming `a` and `b` below are edges

```
voffset = [-20, 0, 0]
Sketchup.active_model.entities.add_dimension_linear(a.start, b.start, voffset)
```

The value of `voffset` controls not just how far offset the dimension is, but also the axis along which the measurement is made. You may need to experiment with different values to get a feeling for how that determination is done.  As with many things in SketchUp, it often guesses (or 'infers') at what you want.